# Isometries of metric spaces $Z=X\cup (X\times\mathbb{R})$ (corrected)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_1)$ be a compact metric space and consider $Z=X\cup (X\times\mathbb{R})$. Consider the metric $d$ on $Z$ defined by:

$$d(x_1,x_2)=d_1(x_1,x_2)$$
$$d(x_1,(x_2,t_2))=d_1(x_1,x_2)+1$$
$$d((x_1,t_1),(x_2,t_2))=d_1(x_1,x_2)+\min\{|t_1-t_2|,1\}$$

where $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

The following statement is something I read in some article, I'll copy it:

> Let $h:Z\to Z$ be an isometry. Then $h(X)=X$ and $h(X\times\mathbb{R})=X\times\mathbb{R}$, since $X$ is compact and $X\times\mathbb{R}$ has only non-compact components.

Obviously $X$ is compact because $d$ and $d_1$ are the same on $X\times X$.

Now, $\rho(t_1,t_2)=\min\{|t_1-t_2|,1\}$ is a topologically equivalent metric to the usual one in $\mathbb{R}$, and $d=d_1+\rho$ on $(X\times\mathbb{R})\times (X\times\mathbb{R})$. This induces the product topology and hence the components of $Y\times\mathbb{R}$ are $C\times\mathbb{R}$ where $C\subseteq Y$ is a component, and $C\times\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

But I can't see why $h(X)=X$ and $h(X\times\mathbb{R})=X\times\mathbb{R}$. If we could prove that $h(X)\subseteq X$ then $h:X\to X$ would be surjective because $X$ is compact. However I don't know how to prove $h(X)\subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it. It seems the author of that article supposed that all isometries are bijective. Some definitions over the internet also say that isometries must be bijective all along, for example:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isometry.html

So we will take $h$ as if it is surjective.

Please let me know if there's no mistake.

It is not difficult to see, by using the definition of $d$, that $X$ and $X\times\mathbb{R}$ are (disjoint) open subspaces of $Z$. Then if $x\in X$, its component $C_x$ is contained in $X$. Since $X$ is compact, $C_x$ is also compact. We know $h:Z\to Z$ is a homeomorphism, so $h(C_x)$ is a compact component of $Z$, which shows it only can be a component of $X$. Hence $h(X)\subseteq X$, then $h(X)=X$ (because $h\restriction_{X}:X\to X$ is isometry and $X$ is compact). It also follows $h(X\times\mathbb{R})=X\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Looks fine, if the author is assuming that $h$ is a bijection. That’s what I was getting hung up on — to the point that I was starting to think about trying to construct a counterexample with a non-surjective $h$.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott I should have known it, it's all about groups of isometries, so an isometry must be bijective.

Comment: You’re welcome. And yes, in that context they’d certainly be bijections. (I still wonder what happens without surjectivity, though I doubt that I’ll spend much time on it.)

Comment: If X,Y are compact Hausdorff spaces and f:X\to Y is a continuous bijection then f is a homeomorphism.